# Android : I got Error "Cannot format given Object as a Date" when converting date from JSON response

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

This is my code. I got error "Cannot format given Object as a Date" when trying to convert my repsonse.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

holder.date.setText(sdf.format(item.getPrice().getDate()));
```

How to convert my repsonse `2017-02-03T11:44:52.6152Z` to 03-February-2017 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to convert your Date String to your format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",Locale.getDefault());
//Date date3 = sdf.parse("2017-02-03T11:44:52.6152Z");
Date date3 = sdf.parse(item.getPrice().getDate());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
String convertedDate= formatter.format(date3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date3 = null;
 date3 = sdf.parse(item.getPrice().getDate());
 formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy");
 String date1 = formatter.format(date3);
 holder.date.setText(date1);
```

Comment: Execption? And what is the date that are you trying to parse? If this: 2017-02-03T11:44:52.6152Z is what you get

Comment: 2017-02-03T11:44:52.6152Z is my JSON response. this is the code to get my response holder.date.setText(sdf.format(item.getPrice().getDate()));

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

1. `Format` takes as `Date` as argument and you are passing `String`.
2. You don't have matching format with the date you have mentioned.

Try below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        try{
       Date a= sdf.parse(item.getPrice().getDate());
       SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyy");
       holder.date.setText(f.format(a));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is the date that i got from my response holder.date.setText(sdf.format(item.getPrice().getDate())); the response is 2017-02-03T11:44:52.6152Z. So, how to make my response to be converted?

Comment: did u try above code(update with your specific case)